# i want to join three tables in sql but cannot get the desired results

Tags: sql

```
SELECT COUNT(TAB1.ID),
       COUNT(TAB2.ID) Results,
       COUNT(TAB3.ID) Dropout 
  FROM TAB1 INNER JOIN  
       TAB2 on TAB1.ID = TAB2.ID INNER JOIN  
       TAB3 on TAB1.ID = TAB3.ID 
 WHERE TAB1.ID='405'

The answer i expect is 2,3,4 but it returns 24,24,24.
```

IT MEANS IT MULTIPLY ENTRIES

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange, please add sample data and desired output, also add (as tag) what is your DBMS

Comment: 2 * 3 * 4 = 24... Coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using distinct count

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct TAB1.ID),COUNT(distinct TAB2.ID) Results,COUNT(distinct 
TAB3.ID) Dropout FROM TAB1 
INNER JOIN  TAB2 on TAB1.ID=TAB2.ID 
INNER JOIN  TAB3 on TAB1.ID=TAB3.ID 
WHERE TAB1.ID='405'
```

Comment: NOT WORKING .
Results  0,0,0

Answer (score 0):

I'd switch to correlated sub-queries:

```
SELECT TAB1.ID, COUNT(TAB1.ID),
       (select COUNT(TAB2.ID) from TAB2 where TAB1.ID=TAB2.ID) Results,
       (select COUNT(TAB3.ID) from TAB3 where TAB1.ID=TAB3.ID) Dropout
FROM TAB1 
WHERE TAB1.ID = '405'  -- to be removed when GROUP BY is added
GROUP BY TAB1.ID  -- more general version
```

Will even return rows having zero Results or Dropouts.

Comment: but first SELECT must return some result , other wise all zero

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that `COUNT(DISTINCT)` does what you want.  Without sample data, it is hard to make a more concrete suggestion:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TAB1.ID), 
       COUNT(DISTINCT TAB2.ID) as Results,
       COUNT(DISTINCT TAB3.ID) as Dropout
FROM TAB1 INNER JOIN
     TAB2 
     ON TAB1.ID = TAB2.ID INNER JOIN
     TAB3 
     ON TAB1.ID = TAB3.ID
WHERE TAB1.ID = '405';  -- Are the single quotes really necessary?
```